# play ad before flv file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, flash

i am using jw player to play an flv file including captions. this seems to work fine. but now i need to play a ad before my flv file starts playing?
or can we play flv files one aftre the another using jquery or any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

JWPlayer has several ad plugins like [this one.](http://www.longtailvideo.com/addons/plugins/80/Adtonomy-Video-Ads-%28Run-Your-Own-Ads%29?q=ad)

Note that you need to buy a JWPlayer license when using it on a commercial site!